# Emails are going to spam

Tags: exchange, email-server, spam, spf, dkim

Hey guys, I am currently running exchange 2010, I have implemented SPF record, and tried to implement dkim/domain keys using domain sink, but it doesn't seem to work. The problem I am having is that all my emails go to spam, whenever I email some one whether it is msn/yahoo/gmail. For Msn i fixed it, since I subscribed to senders framework program.

here are the orignal copies of Gmail and yahoo:

Yahoo:
From Sami Sheikh Wed Jan 27 14:15:51 2010
X-Apparently-To: sunny_3000ca@yahoo.ca via 98.136.167.166; Wed, 27 Jan 2010 06:19:52 -0800
Return-Path: 
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 67.55.9.182
X-YMailISG: 58M0TdIWLDvbv_d_qz4ABPsuq0Fmn1fLYMy08ZnNKPgA1aH3sVNx_KKFsiBK8ZOTBVDwBVnpTvRNkuTZc2UDsNMbj6nV9hfE43MQz3tXRV3.rh62wcp4oqT8AuzKKU5JSxU5g2AH4NzOmT5nGNiRyNEi6xazlMZTDm0rnfWbVECGV4RHzwM1TEadla6Bq_itel6hNinq_6MnPRxu2vX_fddmlCAG1Fi6X0ivjkKPqSr..MvpO8MnlTQTZZjRSoxLZUOqg0vjTPEPary5d_xf3MaS6IsRIScPMMk-
X-Originating-IP: [67.55.9.182]
Authentication-Results: mta1066.mail.mud.yahoo.com  from=; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=SamChrisNetwork.info; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO sam.samchrisnetwork.info) (67.55.9.182)
  by mta1066.mail.mud.yahoo.com with SMTP; Wed, 27 Jan 2010 06:19:52 -0800
Received: from Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55]) by
 Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55%24]) with mapi; Wed, 27
 Jan 2010 09:15:52 -0500
From: Sami Sheikh 
To: "sunny_3000ca@yahoo.ca" 
Subject: Test
Thread-Topic: Test
Thread-Index: AcqfWzrrj8hB3VnJTHC0K4Ev4D+qpw==
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2010 14:15:51 +0000
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-ID: <660dccae-e8e8-4aa0-b13d-5c57052b5335>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 26

Gmail:

Delivered-To: sampimpinthug@gmail.com
Received: by 10.204.102.18 with SMTP id e18cs53728bko;
        Thu, 28 Jan 2010 09:58:46 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.224.116.70 with SMTP id l6mr6467857qaq.157.1264701525683;
        Thu, 28 Jan 2010 09:58:45 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: 
Received: from sam.samchrisnetwork.info (dsl-67-55-9-182.acanac.net [67.55.9.182])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 15si2150271qyk.91.2010.01.28.09.58.45;
        Thu, 28 Jan 2010 09:58:45 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of SheikhS@samchrisnetwork.info designates 67.55.9.182 as permitted sender) client-ip=67.55.9.182;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of SheikhS@samchrisnetwork.info designates 67.55.9.182 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=SheikhS@samchrisnetwork.info
Received: from Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55]) by
 Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55%24]) with mapi; Thu, 28
 Jan 2010 12:58:15 -0500
From: Sami Sheikh 
To: "sampimpinthug@gmail.com" 
Subject: test
Thread-Topic: test
Thread-Index: AcqgQ3ZLj8tW8+jFSA+Vgz5dd1gwMQ==
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2010 17:58:14 +0000
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_000_D8C475B722E95D449334E73DD06751ECB0AF10SamSamChrisNetwor_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_D8C475B722E95D449334E73DD06751ECB0AF10SamSamChrisNetwor_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test

--_000_D8C475B722E95D449334E73DD06751ECB0AF10SamSamChrisNetwor_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns=3D"http:=
//www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

</xml>


</o:shapelayout></xml>test<=
/p>=

--_000_D8C475B722E95D449334E73DD06751ECB0AF10SamSamChrisNetwor

report from Port25:

This message is an automatic response from Port25's authentication verifier service at verifier.port25.com.  The service allows email senders to perform a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at .

Thank you for using the verifier,

The Port25 Solutions, Inc. team

==========================================================

## Summary of Results

SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         neutral
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================

## Details:

HELO hostname:  sam.samchrisnetwork.info
Source IP:      67.55.9.182
mail-from:      SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info

---

### SPF check details:

Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info
DNS record(s):
    SamChrisNetwork.info. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:67.55.9.182/24 mx a:sam.samchrisnetwork.info mx:mail.samchrisnetwork.info mx:sam.samchrisnetwork.info ~all"

---

### DomainKeys check details:

Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info
DNS record(s):

---

### DKIM check details:

Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified:

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs (RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

---

### Sender-ID check details:

Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: header.From=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info
DNS record(s):
    SamChrisNetwork.info. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:67.55.9.182/24 mx a:sam.samchrisnetwork.info mx:mail.samchrisnetwork.info mx:sam.samchrisnetwork.info ~all"

---

### SpamAssassin check details:

SpamAssassin v3.2.5 (2008-06-10)

Result:         ham  (0.6 points, 5.0 required)

pts rule name              description

---

-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-0.7 BAYES_20               BODY: Bayesian spam probability is 5 to 20%
                            [score: 0.1146]
 1.4 AWL                    AWL: From: address is in the auto white-list

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from

## draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):

"pass"
        the message passed the authentication test.

"fail"
        the message failed the authentication test.

"softfail"
        the message failed the authentication test, and the authentication
        method has either an explicit or implicit policy which doesn't require
        successful authentication of all messages from that domain.

"neutral"
        the authentication method completed without errors, but was unable
        to reach either a positive or a negative result about the message.

"temperror"
        a temporary (recoverable) error occurred attempting to authenticate
        the sender; either the process couldn't be completed locally, or
        there was a temporary failure retrieving data required for the
        authentication.  A later retry may produce a more final result.

"permerror"
        a permanent (unrecoverable) error occurred attempting to
        authenticate the sender; either the process couldn't be completed
        locally, or there was a permanent failure retrieving data required
        for the authentication.

==========================================================

## Original Email

Return-Path: 
Received: from sam.samchrisnetwork.info (67.55.9.182) by verifier.port25.com (PowerMTA(TM) v3.6a1) id hc0mn60hse8h for ; Wed, 27 Jan 2010 07:11:31 -0500 (envelope-from )
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com smtp.mail=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info; mfrom=pass;
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com header.From=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed);
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=neutral (message not signed);
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com header.From=SheikhS@SamChrisNetwork.info; pra=pass;
Received: from Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55]) by  Sam.SamChrisNetwork.info ([fe80::b8d3:44f5:68fe:dc55%24]) with mapi; Wed, 27  Jan 2010 09:12:06 -0500
From: Sami Sheikh 
To: "check-auth@verifier.port25.com" 
Subject: Test
Thread-Topic: Test
Thread-Index: AcqfWrTNJAbICp6MQsiQwUi89zjagw==
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2010 14:12:04 +0000
Message-ID: <7F8B8F33-B676-4736-8F74-AA7B40777F20@SamChrisNetwork.info>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-ID: 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

Test

Sent from my iPhone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent mail being marked as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam)

Answer (score 1):

The following is based off of the IP I see in your logs as the mail sending IP of 67.55.9.182.

You have a PTR entry, which is good.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
182.9.55.67.in-addr.arpa. 14400 IN      PTR     dsl-67-55-9-182.acanac.net.
```

However your forward and reverse should match ideally. The reverse entry leads me to believe that you are running this off of a DSL ISP connection. That is enough to get your mail marked as spam in some systems. They do not like seeing mail coming from "home" or "consumer" connections.

Your IP is also listed in [several blacklists](http://www.anti-abuse.org/checkrbl.php?host=67.55.9.182&submit.x=23&submit.y=18):

```
67.55.9.182 is listed in dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net 
67.55.9.182 is listed in bl.spamcannibal.org
```

This will also result in your mail being sent to the spam bin.

Resolve the above issues and you will likely see your mail being accepted as ham. Hope that helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I checked spamvannibal, and it says that i don't have a reversedns, and uceprotect, and they are saying that my whole isp is flagged as spam. 

Now for the reverse DNS, can I create a reverse DNS from the dns server in server 2k8 and then if it does a reverse look up, will it come to my domain name?

Comment: Reverse DNS is handled by your ISP. Any PTR is likely not delegated to your local Windows Server 2k8 and any that you add would not be recognized across the internet. Unless you have some special setup from your ISP.

Comment: So what are the possible solutions, if I can't add a reverse DNS, and a PTR? Can I ask my ISP to put a PTR pointing from static IP to my domain:SamChrisNetwork.info? would this help?

Also, how can I implement DKIM in my server?