# Can message go to spam because of X-AUTH and X-SID fail on hotmail

Tags: email, email-server, spam

When email with header as below comes to hotmail, it is put into spam folder. May be this is because of X-AUTH-Result: FAIL or X-SID-Result: FAIL? Or maybe the reason is different?How can I fix this?

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 114.112.255.122)     smtp.mailfrom=www-data@uniquemobiles.com.au; dkim=none header.d=uniquemobiles.com.au; x-    hmca=fail header.id=sales@uniquemobiles.com.au
X-SID-PRA: sales@uniquemobiles.com.au
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: 2etWe3f/w1cLzNMFGWUkxI4X8GWjUgRPldCSLaHlMPz8KnnMw4wBLDZs45EYPr3D2LbW9QLPCct0MQQSuVuU4zU05+QEV84llG4Dg802VOeHLX90x3RbeXG0tmVB1as7GPr5ogCj2Y5rfmkYkroQia15I9SlWXAaM4gmU/Jw3y3yzUlB8kZ3Ihqkx5o9o96DUIgQU8BZOI3s1cj++xdMrorb6Gh1fAHR
Received: from uniquemobiles.com.au ([114.112.255.122]) by BAY0-MC2-F21.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
 Mon, 2 Sep 2013 21:08:45 -0700
Received: from uniquemobiles.com.au (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by uniquemobiles.com.au (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) with ESMTP id r8341iG1014318
for <rissa_mol@hotmail.com>; Tue, 3 Sep 2013 12:01:44 +0800
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
by uniquemobiles.com.au (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r8341iuD014317;
Tue, 3 Sep 2013 12:01:44 +0800
Message-Id: <201309030401.r8341iuD014317@uniquemobiles.com.au>
To: =?utf-8?B?QW50aG9ueSBSaXNpdGFubw==?= <rissa_mol@hotmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?VW5pcXVlIE1vYmlsZXM6IE9yZGVyICMgMTU3NDc1Njc3IHVwZGF0ZQ==?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 505:Sendmail.php
From: Unique Mobiles Sales <sales@uniquemobiles.com.au>
Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 04:01:44 +0000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: www-data@uniquemobiles.com.au
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Sep 2013 04:08:45.0462 (UTC) FILETIME=[48A58360:01CEA85B]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your email has at least two issues which may cause it to be seen as spam.

---

First, your SPF record doesn't actually contain the address of the mail server you sent this mail from.

When I looked it up moments ago, it read:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all
```

Of course you also used `~all` which effectively makes the whole record useless. To actually make this work it should be `-all`, and the IP addresses of your sending mail servers should be present. ([Learn how to create an SPF record](https://serverfault.com/q/369460/126632))

For example:

```
v=spf1 ip4:114.112.255.122 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

Second, your `Subject` and `To` headers contain plain ASCII text which was gratuitously encoded when it did not need to be. Unnecessary encoding of any of the mail headers is often used as an indicator of possible spam.

Had they not been encoded, the headers would have read:

```
To: Anthony Risitano <rissa_mol@hotmail.com>
Subject: Unique Mobiles: Order # 157475677 update
```

As you can see there was no need to encode those as they did not have any non-ASCII characters.

To resolve this you will need to modify the software which sent the email.

---

Any other possible reason is solely within Hotmail's control, and not something you will be able to fix.