# How to correctly configure postfix and opendkim and let receiving server know all details mailed-by signed-by?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dkim, domainkeys

What I am trying to achieve - Bottomline:
mails to go in inbox rather spam folder.

I have a server which is running postfix (mail server) and I have 3 domains.
Mail server is used for both incoming and outgoing mails..

I am signing with opendkim and have DNS records in place.

After a long observation, I've realized that messages are going in spam due to incorrect mailed-by and signed-by assignment.

consider, my mail server to be mailserver.example.com and 3 other domains are example1.com, example2.com and example3.com

when someone sends an email from admin@example1.com , it should display:

admin@example1.com via mailserver.example.com

mailed-by: mailserver.example.com

signed-by: example1.com

I have observed that mailjet and amazon emails hardly go into spam, the fact is, 'maybe' because the originating hostname / ip reverse resolves to what mailed-by and signed-by are.

Config files:

`/etc/opendkim/Keytable`

```
mvs._domainkey.example1.com example1.com:selc:/etc/opendkim/keys/example1_com/selc.private
mvs._domainkey.example2.com example2.com:selc:/etc/opendkim/keys/example2_com/selc.private
```

`/etc/opendkim.conf`

```
Domain          example1.com
KeyFile     /etc/opendkim/keys/example1_com/selc
Selector        selc

Domain          example2.com
KeyFile     /etc/opendkim/keys/example2_com/selc
Selector        selc

Canonicalization    simple
Mode            sv
Syslog                  yes
LogWhy                  yes
UMask                   022
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
KeyTable           /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable       /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
Socket                  inet:34562@localhost
X-Header        no
```

and finally

`/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`

```
example1.com selc._domainkey.example1.com
example2.com selc._domainkey.example2.com
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: How does SPF come into this question?

Comment: By error. Edited. Do you have answer?

Comment: No, but if you'd wanted SPF guidance as well I'd've moved to close this question as being overbroad, plus SPF configuration questions are OT as duplicates of the canonical SPF question at http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them/.

Comment: Yea... I read that answer whilst updating my spf stuff... However, am bit held up with DKIM... If u might know... I have this DKIM for example1 and example2 and when i generate for mail.example and submit that as DKIM it would fail the auth, which ... is logically self-explanatory but... any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, please remove these values (they aren't needed if you use KeyTable):

```
Domain      example1.com
KeyFile     /etc/opendkim/keys/example1_com/selc
Selector    selc

Domain      example2.com
KeyFile     /etc/opendkim/keys/example2_com/selc
Selector    selc
```

Setup your **KeyTable** like that:

```
mykey1 example1.com:recordname1:/path/to/domain.key
mykey2 example2.com:recordname2:/path/to/domain.key
```

Setup your **SigningTable** like that (note wildcard matching and *mykey1* and *mykey2* from **KeyTable**):

```
*@example1.com mykey1
*@example2.com mykey2
```

And finally change your **opendkim.conf** to include **SigningTable** via *refile:* prefix (regular expressions support):

```
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
```

And domain record for reference (note *recordname1* and *recordname2* from **KeyTable**):

```
recordname1._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=..."
recordname2._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=..."
```

Additionally, please, check if you have your node hostname (from which you are sending mail) in **InternalHosts** file:

```
server1.example1.com
server2.example2.com
mail.example1.com
mail.example2.com
```

Again, you can use *refile:* prefix to be able to add something like:

```
*.example1.com
*.example2.com
```

if you have multiple hosts and do not want to include all of them by hand. If you accept only local mail, you should add **localhost** here.

You should check log file for **DKIM** notices about skipping signing if your host is missing in the **InternalHosts** file.

Example of opendkim.conf:

```
# Set these values (Syslog, SyslogSuccess, LogWhy) for debugging and check syslog for details
Syslog      yes
SyslogSuccess   yes
LogWhy      yes

UMask       002
UserID      opendkim:opendkim

KeyTable            /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable        refile:/etc/mail/SigningTable
InternalHosts       refile:/etc/mail/hosts
```

Comment: Hey fantastic! Lemme try out...

Comment: mykey1 example1.com:recordname1:/path/to/domain.key
mykey2 example2.com:recordname2:/path/to/domain.key

mykey1 and mykey2 = DNS TXT record key names?

Comment: What is an `InternalHosts`. Rest all done...

Comment: You have included it in your opendkim.conf:
InternalHosts      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
This file contains all hosts for which messages will be signed.

recordname1 and recordname2 are DNS TXT records. mykey1 and mykey2 are for internal usage, for example to link emails to specific keys

Comment: UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
KeyTable           /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
Socket                  inet:12345@localhost

Comment: my externalIgnreList and InternalHosts are same file... is that correct?

Comment: done... now I am getting Relay access denied - SMTP error 554

Comment: Can you show an example file...?

Comment: Hi, I just tried that... it says mailed-by - example1, signed-by - example1... but I sending email via example2...

Comment: Are you sure what SigningTable is correctly configured?
*@example1.com mykey1 <==
*@example2.com mykey2 <==
note mykey1 and mymkey2

Comment: yes... SigningTable is correct... Also, Gmail tells me, signed-by example.com but I want mailed-by to be the server from where emails are being sent... as in... we are hosted solutions...

Comment: ExternalIgnoreList is used to suppress LOG messages like "External host trying to send mail via our SMTP server"

Comment: Do you have "dkim=pass" in message source (which come to your gmail)? Or dkim= neutral or fail?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12088/discussion-between-greshnik-and-karmicdice)