# opendkim only signs for 1 zone on a hosted server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, dns-hosting, dkim, opendkim

I am implementing opendkim but I can only get it to sign for 1 zone.
The tld is failing to sign even though it is the same key/signature/file for both domains.

my .conf:

```
cat /usr/local/etc/mail/opendkim.conf

LogWhy                 yes
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

Socket                  inet:8891@107.191.60.48
MilterDebug             5
ReportAddress           postmaster@e-mailer.com
SendReports             yes

InternalHosts           file:/usr/local/etc/TrustedHostList.txt
SigningTable            refile:/var/db/opendkim/dkim-signtable
KeyTable                file:/var/db/opendkim/dkim-keytable
```

signing table:

```
cat /var/db/opendkim/dkim-signtable
*@nyctelecomm.com nycmap
*@e-mailer.com emailmap
```

key table going to the same key:

```
cat /var/db/opendkim/dkim-keytable
emailmap e-mail.com:default:/var/db/opendkim/keys/e-mailer.com.key
nycmap nyccomm.com:default:/var/db/opendkim/keys/e-mailer.com.key
```

response from port25.com:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (key "default._domainkey.e-mail.com" doesn't exist)
ID(s) verified: 
Canonicalized Headers:
    from:"user"'20'<user@e-mailer.com>'0D''0A'
    to:<check-auth@verifier.port25.com>'0D''0A'
    subject:'0D''0A'
    date:Mon,'20'16'20'Mar'20'2015'20'16:53:33'20'-0400'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=ex-mail.com;'20's=default;'20't=1426539201;'20'bh=MhPgNzFR7ZDrllybqjf7Ky1x0INMPJ5OEWy00nl+zGI=;'20'h=From:To:Subject:Date;'20'b=
```

just like  ->  [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/558629/how-to-correctly-configure-postfix-and-opendkim-and-let-receiving-server-know-al)

How do I get opendkim to sign both of my domains and not just one?

Comment: You have both `ex-mail.com` and `exmail-er.com` in your key table. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Paul dang, I don't know how I missed that. Post it as an answer and I will click the button

Comment: Just as an FYI, Stack Exchange has a feature where posting a link to question within a given Q&A site will be displayed as the question title with link.

Comment: Cheers!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `ex-mail.com` to `ex-mailer.com` in your key file.