# SPF keeps on failing

Tags: email-server, spf, gmail

Based on this  link [how to set up SPF](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404314/how-can-i-create-an-spf-record-for-my-domain) and answer in closed topic  [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/586461/how-to-resolve-problems-with-spf-softfail) My dns record looks like this

```
 v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xx.xx -all include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

but google throws an error

> spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@smmmoney.com does not designate xx.xx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@smmmoney.com;

Is my record valid? Why doesn't it pass Gmail's filter?
I am using PLESK  17.8.11 on VPS server.

EDIT 2

My domain is smmmoney.com.
Changed as advised but still not working. 
Dns shows record is up to date.

Comment: Tell us the domain name(s) and addresses in question.  We can't give proper help without a clear problem statement.

Comment: Whatever is your problem now, it's different and an error message is probably different. If so, please close this question and ask again with a new error message. This way the site will be readable for others in future.

Comment: "Changed as advised but still not working." Gmail likely caches it for a bit. Wait 24 hours and retry.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `-all` in the middle of the record.
`all` practically only makes sense at the end of the record.
Most likely everything after the `-all` is ignored by receiving servers.

Comment: [RFC 7208 section 5.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-5.1) states: `Mechanisms after "all" will never be tested.  Mechanisms listed after "all" MUST be ignored.`

Answer (score 1):

You have -all and ~all in your record.
Try with:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xx.xx include:_spf.google.com -all
```

Also did you verify that all of your DNS servers for example.com are correctly updated?

```
host -t ns example.com
host -t txt example.com name-of-dns1
host -t txt example.com name-of-dns2
```

and so on...