# DKIM - DomainKey Identified Mail public key longer than 512 character

Tags: vps, dkim, spam-filter

I've generated private key and public key using following commands.

openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.insecure

mv server.key server.key.secure
mv server.key.insecure server.key

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

it shows error message while verifying for DKIM that public key(server.crt) should not be longer than 512 character.

Comment: You may also wish to read [our canonical question on SPF configuration](http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them).

Comment: You really have a shotgun approach to tagging. Adding tons of irrelevant ones. Oh, and btw - where does SPF appear, outside the tag and title? Because the question is not about SPF but DKIM.

Answer (score 2):

SPF doesn't use certificates, so you have misunderstood mechanisms used by SPF to stop the use of forged "from" addresses.

[SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) is based on set a DNS TXT record in which you specify simple policies of what hosts can send mails using your domain name like this:

```
v=spf1 mx a:pluto.example.net include:aspmx.googlemail.com -all
```

You are probably confused with [DKIM](http://dkim.org/).