# SPF softfail domain does not designate IP as permitted sender

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, namecheap

I use both mailgun and a namecheap mail server (where I also have my domain) and when I receive mails in my gmail account, mailgun is recognized as a permitted sender, but that's not the case of namecheap. That's what I get:

*Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning xx@mydomain does not designate ... as permitted sender)*

I have the following TXT record in my DNS

```
v=spf1 mx include:mailgun.org ~all
```

It's an IPv4 and I read some other posts in serverfault with no luck, so any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

As stated [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/322/78/how-can-i-setup-mx-record-for-my-domain), Namecheap private mail sets up the MX records automatically and they are not shown on the DNS record list, I guess that has something to do with the fact that it was not recognized as a permitted sender when I had the MX record in the spf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Comment: @MadHatter I read your answer before writing my question, I probably should have mention it, please see my edit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution, in the end I added the mail server IP to the TXT record and now gmail accepts the sender.
If anyone is interested, this is how it looks like:

```
v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:mailgun.org ~all
```