# SPF Error with redirection

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, spf, ospf

so I have this crazy SPF-Policy problem which looks like that:

I have a private domain like 'my-private-domain.com'. This one I'm hosting myself on a vServer and I activated SPF and added the SPF keys and so on. Works good to receive messages from freemail hosters , gmail and so on.

I also have a managed website-package at a hoster which offers some emails to a domain like : 'my-company-domain.com' . So I added a redirection at this domain, so that every mail which comes to "info@my-company-domain.com" is redirected to "me@my-private-domain.com" (and some other members of the company).

So I came across this on: I just sent a mail from "me@my-private-domain.com" to "info@my-company-domain.com" ... so basically this mail should come back to me (and comes to some co-workers)

But after the message was sent, I got an error from the mailer-daemon that:

```
This is the mail system at host somehost.my-company-domain.com .

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<me@my-private-domain.com> (expanded from <info@my-company-domain.com>): host
    my-private-domain.com.de[79.143.186.XXX] said: 550 5.7.1 <me@my-private-domain.com>:
    Recipient address rejected: Please see
    http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=me@my-private-domain.com;ip=85.13.XXX.XX;r=host.my-private-domain.com
    (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Any ideas what went wrong there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them).  Basically, simplistic redirection (ie, redirection without using SRS) and SPF are incompatible.  Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide spf record that you've set and header of email that was rejected. Reason for rejection is spf settings so you either didn't include sending server to your spf record or record itself is not valid.