# One SPF Recored different Hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, spf

We are working with bind9 in our center and we have two different mail servers. One is for our company domain and the other is for customer domains. At the moment we have the simple entry in the file:

```
SPF     "v=spf1 mx -all"
TXT     "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

This works great for our company server and don't makes any problems.

Now we have the customer server where we get a few complains there is a problem with sending mails or automaticly forwarding them. When we say there is mail1.test.net and mail2.test.net, how should the SPF record look like so both servers are included?

I tryed it with:

```
                         MX    10 mail1.test.net
                               "v=spf1 mx include:mail2.test.net -all"
mail2.test.net.    IN    TXT   "v=spf1 a:mail2.test.net -all"
```

But as you can think, this didn't work at all.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891765/spf-multiple-servers

Comment: You may want to read this: http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes

Comment: Great, that seems to work as I whish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Answer (score 0):

Add "a:" for each host that will send mail for that domain.

```
testdomain.com.      IN TXT     "v=spf1 mx a:mail1.testserver.com a:mail2.testserver.com -all"
```

will allow both mail1.testserver.com and mail2.testserver.com as well as any servers listed with a MX record.