# Why does SPF allow +all?

Tags: email, spf

I was looking at how various sites have their SPF records set, and found a site whose SPF record ends with `+all`.

This seems to be a bad idea, and [spf-all](http://spf-all.com/) says the following about the matter:

> +all  Pass    The email is never a forgery. This option should not be used.

Yet I cannot find anything in the RFC that says this is banned, so it appears to be a valid record.

Is this a valid record? And if so, would most spam filters treat this as an indication to raise the required level of *spammyness* of a message from this domain before it is treated as spam, or would it simply ignore the record, or count it against the domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Comment: @JennyD That question is about SPF in general, this asks about a specific case, I'd have thought that makes it not a duplicate

Comment: It's a duplicate for two reasons. First, it does contain the answer to your specific question. Second, it's a [canonical question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years), meaning that it's the last word on that topic.

Comment: The only specific reference I could find to +all in the 2 answers is `and +all is an abomination.`, there are a few instances where it is mentioned coincidentally, but not the rationale behind it not being banned, or how it can be used for good. I agree that a question on setting up SPF would be a duplicate of the canonical, but if all SPF questions fall under the canonical question then should the tag be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPF is defined in [RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208).

The "all" keywork is defined as such:

> 5.1.  "all"
>
> all              = "all"
>
> The "all" mechanism is a test that always matches.  It is used as the
> rightmost mechanism in a record to provide an explicit default.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  v=spf1 a mx -all
> ```
>
> Mechanisms after "all" will never be tested.  Mechanisms listed after
> "all" MUST be ignored.  Any "redirect" modifier (Section 6.1) MUST be
> ignored when there is an "all" mechanism in the record, regardless of
> the relative ordering of the terms.

You even have this example:

```
v=spf1 +all

  -- any <ip> passes
```

or

```
example.com.           SPF  ( "v=spf1 "
                              "-include:ip4._spf.%{d} "
                              "-include:ptr._spf.%{d} "
                              "+all" )
ip4._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ip4:192.0.2.0/24 +all"
ptr._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ptr +all"

This example shows how the "-include" mechanism can be useful, how an
SPF record that ends in "+all" can be very restrictive, and the use
of De Morgan's Law.
```

So `+all` is useful, and certainly not banned.

As for spam filters, it is difficult to say how they treat it, this is a local policy configuration.