# where should i add dkim records when using custom name servers?

Tags: dkim

I have recently setup mail server on ubuntu14.04 using postfix, dovecot. I am very confused about adding dkim records. Every tutorial i have followed is saying i should add dkim at domain registrar but i am using custom nameserver like ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com so there is no option to add txt records now.
So my question is where should i add dkim. BTW i am also using bind9 on ubuntu

Comment: Why would you set up anything new on Ubuntu 14.04 now? It will soon be EOL. Using 18.04 would be a more sensible choice.

Comment: Why can't you add TXT records to your name server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Comment: @kasperd I am currently learning to setup server and i found ubuntu 14.04 is easier to learn and setup as compare to 18.04.

Comment: I can't add TXT records to domain because i have setup bind and using private nameservers so records can not be managed from domain registrar.

Answer (score 3):

For DKIM records to work need to be added to whatever namer servers are authoritative for your domain so that, like any other public DNS record, those records will be available to any internet system that needs to query them.

When you host your own DNS, yes that will be your own servers. If your DNS is managed by somebody else, you will need (to ask your provider) to add them at whatever provider you use...