# How to build "SPF" ( multiple IPs) for authorizing other domains for sending mails behalf of them

Tags: email-server, spf

We are building mail server to send mails for other domains.

We have multiple IP address and i have created "A" record like `spf.example.com` pointing to multiple IP's

Now I have asked client to include our `spf.xyz.com` in their SPF record to authorize send mails behalf of them.

We are getting error like

> "- PermError SPF Permanent Error: No valid SPF record for included domain:"

What would be the problem? Is the process we are following is right?

Comment: The process seems okay to me. But the question is how the customer is implenting it. You can check it out easily with the domain name, using online tools, to see if it is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Comment: Since you have created an "A" record, the clients should use the "A" mechanism to use your record in their SPF records: "a:spf.xyz.com". If you instead create an SPF record for spf.xyz.com containing the multiple IP's "ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 ip4:3.3.3.3" the clients can use the "include" mechanism "include:spf.xyz.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have instructed your clients to include `spf.example.com` in their SPF record to allow your mailservers to send mail on their behalf.

I.e. Your customers now have something like this set up:

```
v=spf1 a mx  include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf.example.com -all
```

That is perfectly valid.

> I have created "A" record like spf.example.com pointing to multiple IP's

That is probably the problem. AFAIK  The `include:spf.example.com`  mechanism is designed to *include **other SPF records***, not `A` records

Instead of

```
spf.example.com. IN A 10.9.8.7
spf.example.com. IN A 192.168.0.1
```

a valid SPF record is needed, something along the line below is expected:

```
spf.example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:10.9.8.7/32 ip4:192.168.0.1/32"
```