# SPF Error - Cannot send emails to @gmail users

Tags: email, spf, gmail

I get the following error, every time I tried to send an email to a gmail user.

```
Error:"This is the mail system at host chimaera.otenet.gr.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<geo.georgiadis94@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]
    said: 550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [tatoocdc.com] has an SPF record with
    a hard 550-5.7.26 fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF checks with
    the ip: 550-5.7.26 [83.235.69.32]. To best protect our users from spam and
    phishing, 550-5.7.26 the message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. g8-20020a056000118800b0023660cfe509si9240960wrx.90 -
    gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; chimaera.otenet.gr
X-mailgate-otenet-gr-Queue-ID: E204B14F248
X-mailgate-otenet-gr-Sender: rfc822; timoleon@tatoocdc.com
Arrival-Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2022 17:04:56 +0200 (EET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; geo.georgiadis94@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;geo.georgiadis94@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.26
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [tatoocdc.com] has an
    SPF record with a hard 550-5.7.26 fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass
    SPF checks with the ip: 550-5.7.26 [83.235.69.32]. To best protect our
    users from spam and phishing, 550-5.7.26 the message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. g8-20020a056000118800b0023660cfe509si9240960wrx.90 -
    gsmtp"
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems your question was already answered: You decide who is designated as permitted sender for your domain. What else do you want to know? Did you read what Google has been so kind to document on their support pages? Did you follow some other documentation after looking up the referenced keyword *SPF*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them)

Answer (score 0):

Your SPF policy denotes who are allowed to send email on behalf of your domain. It [currently looks like](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3atatoocdc.com&run=toolpage):

```
 tatoocdc.com.      14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +a:tatoocdc.com -all"
```

The server that was attempting to send e-mail, with IP-address 83.235.69.32, is not included in that list in any way. Therefor gmail refused to accept the message. Exactly how your SPF record is configured.

If 83.235.69.32, with a hostname of `smtp-out32.otenet.gr.` should be allowed to send e-mail for your domain, then the SPF record should be amended to include that host.

Set for example `"v=spf1 +a +mx +a:tatoocdc.com +ip4:83.235.69.32 -all"`

Comment: Hello mr diya and thank you for your prompt reply.

I set "v=spf1 +a +mx +a:tatoocdc.com +ip4:83.235.69.32 -all" as my SPF Record.

Nothing change.

Comment: Two  possibilities, DNS records get cached and it might take up to your TTL of 14400 seconds before the cache with the old record expires; and/or your mail providers load balances outgoing SMTP traffic and the second message passed through a diferent server, with a different IP