# How to send emails without ending up in Junk/Spam folder

Tags: email-server, spam

I have installed a mail server in order to send e-mails using my own domain name. 
I've read many articles about how not to end up in Junk folder. I have done what those articles said:

- Added MX record
- Added SPF record
- Added domain key
- Added DMARC
- Successfully set reverse dns record
- Added postmaster, abuse accounts
- Added real first name and surname values for the sender account
- Tested on mail-tester.com and got 10/10 validation: http://www.mail-tester.com/web-N2jQha

Even tough I have done all of above, when I sent a test e-mail without images or suspicious words etc., it ended up in Junk folder all the same. (Tested for Outlook and Gmail)

This is the e-mail's original content for Gmail: http://pastebin.com/n83WMC3x

What else should i do? I am out of ideas.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam

Comment: I checked, domain name don't seem to be in any blacklist. My SPF, MX, DKIM, Domain Key, reverse DNS is valid. I've just started e-mailing so I don't think it is in flood category. I tested in the links you provided, seems all OK. What else?

Comment: From the headers it seems that your server uses IPv6 to connect to Gmail's and no reverse IPv6 DNS record seems to have been setup. No idea if that makes a huge difference, but you might try to force IPv4 and get a different result.

Comment: `1.` MX records have nothing to do with your server `sending` email. `2.` While you can follow every accepted best practice, in the end there's no guarantee that your email will never end up in a spam filter or junk mail folder.

Comment: @HBruijn I've set IPv6 reverse DNS, still no luck.

Comment: @joeqwerty My e-mail is pretty simple, and really far from being a spam and only contains letters. I guess I am stuck.