# Error when delivering email to Gmail from my server, and MX records for sub-domains

Tags: subdomain, mx-record, gmail

I hope I'm posting in the right forum.

I'm having some trouble with email being sent from a forum I run. The email is coming directly from the sub-domain, as in notifications@community.example.com (not the actual domain).

Google seems to be rejecting digests I send, yet not rejecting full email notifications, even though both are sent from the same address. The error message is of this form:

```
  01-Nov-14 02:40:14 smtp-out error ID=46 Send email. Mail delivery error (-4.7.0 [my-ip-address 15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of some-other-ip-address:destination-domain) To: my-email-address From: bounce.2fbf9af.132@community.example.com
```

This is just a test server, with just 3 users, and a very low amount of mail sent (like <10 per day). my-ip-address is the IP address of the server. some-other-ip-address is some other IP address - I'm not sure what. and my-email-address is my personal email address. The notifications are being sent to me for my testing.

Does anybody know how to deal with this kind of error?

Also, while my full domain itself has an MX record, I did not create a separate MX record for the sub-domain community.example.com. I never have in the past for any of our servers and it has never been a problem before.

I always thought MX records are not required for fully-substantiated hosts. Is that true? Might an MX record help with this problem? If so, how do you create an MX record for a sub-domain and not the domain itself? I wouldn't want to interfere with email destined for the full domain, which is working fine.

Comment: Related [Prevent mail being marked as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam). Basically, *marked as spam* has the same cause with *rejection with 4XX* code.

Comment: Anyway, not having MX record for subdomain wasn't big issue for email deliverability.

Comment: Thanks. I looked over the list & all seems ok. (1) the digest emails are just being sent to me so there have been no complaints, (2) the IP address is a dedicated IP address that is just used by this test server and there is no smtp relay open and (3) most importantly, individual email notifications (not digests) are not being blocked by Gmail. Only the digests are. But the content is the same. So it's not a matter of "spammy content." It is a huge mystery to me why this is happening just to the digests. The only one I'm not sure of is the SPF setting. But why would that affect just digests?

Comment: What's even stranger is that sometimes the digest will get through. One did just now, but I don't know why. Same digest.

Comment: And using the tools there, the IP address is not on any blacklist: Checking xx.xxx.xxx.xx against 87 known blacklists...
Listed 0 times with 0 timeouts