# Outlook is rejecting emails without any notification

Tags: postfix, smtp, outlook, spf, opendkim

i have configured postfix with opendkim. Everything is working fine, I have tested DKIM records as well as DMARC and SPF, everything seems fine. I am also receiving emails on my gmail account in Inbox. But when I try to send email to Outlook.com, the email does not work. Also, I do not see any error in the mail log.

Mail log:

> Apr 16 17:51:34postfix/smtp[4778]: E6911060F:
>   to=<*******@hotmail.com>, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72]:25,
>   delay=2, delays=0.09/0/1.2/0.75, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 
>    Queued mail
>   for delivery) Apr 16 17:51:34 postfix/qmgr[4697]: E6911060F:
>   removed

I do not receive in either junk or inbox @ hotmail. Seems as Outlook is just rejecting the email.

Couple of days ago everything was working fine, but I was receiving email in the junk, then I did setup DKIM, I started getting emails in the Inbox but after somedays I stopped receiving email to my Outlook at all, I do not see any error too.

In my SPF records I am using: `"v=spf1 a ~all"`

And when I try to send an email from Outlook to my email@domain.org
I do receive the email, but in the logs this is what I see.

```
Apr 16 17:53:22 postfix/smtpd[5016]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-oln040092255027.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.255.27]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Apr 16 17:53:23 postfix/smtpd[5016]: 3F45D4060F: client=mail-oln040092255027.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.255.27]
Apr 16 17:53:23 postfix/cleanup[5023]: 3F45D4060F: message-id=<HK2PR02MB0450CFA68BB6B5A2CD033A8EEB70@HK2PR02MB0450.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com>
Apr 16 17:53:23 opendkim[819]: 3F45D4060F: mail-oln040092255027.outbound.protection.outlook.com [40.92.255.27] not internal   
Apr 16 17:53:23  opendkim[819]: 3F45D4060F: not authenticated
Apr 16 17:53:23 opendkim[819]: 3F45D4060F: failed to parse authentication-results: header field
Apr 16 17:53:23 opendkim[819]: 3F45D4060F: DKIM verification successful
```

I am still confused. can anyone detect the issue? If you need anymore configurations please let me know.

Comment: Without the domain it's hard to tell - run your domain through the tools at mxtoolbox.com and see if there are any issues or you're on any blacklists?

Comment: Nope everything seems good.

Comment: It's not rejecting them, it's accepting them without delivering them. The only person who can answer why it does that is the email admins at Hotmail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent mail being marked as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam)

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd think that the SPF is kind of bad, and without the domain is really hard to say anything.

domain.org.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:65.54.188.72 ip4:0.0.0.0/32 ~all"
( I personally always use http://www.spfwizard.net/)

The domain should be something like  (I'm just guessing that your public IP is 65.54.188.72, the other ip is an example of how to put a range.

Also, you can be sent an email to http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim
to test if your configuration of DKIM is good (you need to click the link and then send the email to the address the web app will show you) then wait for the report on the same page.

Comment: Hi, I did try the links you send me. but still I am not receiving the email to my outlook account. The result is: http://i.imgur.com/FghOpxy.png

Comment: Ok check if you're blacklisted https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Nope, it's not black listed. I can share you the domain, but can't here in public.

Comment: what about being blacklisted in a hotmail lists
https://www.rackaid.com/blog/hotmail-blacklist-removal/

Comment: that did not work. However, I added the domain to hotmail's safe sender's list and now I am able to receive the emails. While reading the email source I see that it shows `Received: from localhost.localdomain (unknown: 0.0.0.0)` , however the hostname is the domain.org, I am using docker over proxy to send emails i.e. docker IP contacts the server, so this localhost.localdomain is actually docker's IP host and IP. Even on docker the hostname is `domain.org`